# MongoDB: Running as Process vs Service

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MondoDB and just setting it up for the first time in Windows 8. I've followed a tutorial which tells me to run `mongod.exe` from the command line, which seems to work fine. However, when I run my server which uses MongoDB (I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 with Visual Studio 2013), do I have to keep this command prompt open the entire time?

I have been looking at another PC which is running MongoDB in Windows XP, and has been set up by an expert previously (but unfortunately I cannot contact him now) and is running well with the server. However, there is no command prompt open. How would he have done this?

If I open Task Manager on my PC and his PC, one key difference I spot is that on my PC, there is a process called `Mongod` running, whereas on his PC there is no such process, and instead there is a Service called `MongoDB` running. Please can somebody explain to a rookie what the difference is between these two setups? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If any application is installed as a service , operating system will automatically load the  program into memory and to run it. The user does not have to worry about manual start and shutdown . Installation as service  is quite easy , refer [mongoDB official document for installation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)

.

Answer (score -1):

The difference is obvious. One is a process and the other is a service (no need to explain that here).

If you want the `mongod` server always up and running then you have to install it as a service. There is an installation guide in MongoDB official site:

- [Configure a Windows Service for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb)